# unable to create a constant value of type when trying to match emails from list with another list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I'm trying to find out if there is any emails in one of my lists that exists in my database table.

```
   var existinctContactAccount = _dataContext.ContactAccounts
            .Include(ca => ca.Contact)
            .Include(ca => ca.ContactAccountTags.Select(cat => cat.ContactTag))
            .Where(ca =>
                ca.AccountId == accountId &&
                addCustomContactAccounts.Any(a => a.Email.Equals(ca.Contact.Email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))).ToList();
```

This is how i'm trying to do it but all i get is "unable to create a constant value of type".

Comment: What is the `Type` of the exception thrown?

Comment: Use `addCustomContactAccounts.Contains(ca.Contact.Email)` You can use `IEqualityComparer<T>` as a second argument to justify comparison.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work because you try to work with a collection of objects in memory and you cannot join a set of data in the database with another set of data that is in memory. You need to first select all data from DB and then from memory. To do that use .ToList() after db query methods.

So try something like this:

```
var existinctContactAccount = _dataContext.ContactAccounts
            .Include(ca => ca.Contact)
            .Include(ca => ca.ContactAccountTags.Select(cat => cat.ContactTag))
            .ToList()
            .Where(ca =>
                ca.AccountId == accountId &&
                addCustomContactAccounts.Any(a => a.Email.Equals(ca.Contact.Email, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))).ToList();
```

Comment: But this will get all data from that table? That can't be the right way to do it?